# Unable to sign the android apk while using calabash

Tags: android, calabash

I am trying to use calabash tool for automation of android application, while signing application I got following error:

```
jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: 
C:\Users\pcadmin.INFPU08742\.keystore (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

I have debug.keystore file in `./android` folder

Please let me know what is required?

Answer (score 0):

How are you signing the apk? If it's through the terminal it can become quite a huge mess. At least that happened to me. A quick solution is simply to get the signed apk from eclipse -> right click on Application package(in package explorer) -> Android tools -> Export Signed apk. Just specify the keystore location and use ***android*** as password. That should do the trick.